# Fast allocation of linked list and slow deallocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list

I'm a C++ novice and I've run into a frustrating problem -

I have this templated LinkedList implementation:

```
template <typename U>
class LinkedList : std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, U> {
public:
    struct Node {
    friend LinkedList;
        U content;
        Node* getNext() { return next; };
    private:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    };

    LinkedList() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) { };
    ~LinkedList() {
        Node * current = tail;
        while(current != NULL) {
            Node* temp = current;
            current = current->prev;
            delete temp;
        }
    };
    Node* getHead() { return head; }
    Node* getTail() { return tail; }
    bool append(U content) {
        Node* node = new Node();
        if(node == NULL) return false;

        node->content = content;
        if(tail == NULL) {
            tail = head = node;
        } else {
            tail->next = node;
            node->prev = tail;
            tail = node;
        }

        return true;
    };

bool remove(U* cont) {
    if(tail == NULL) return false;

    if(cont != NULL) *cont = tail->content;

    Node *temp = tail;
    if(tail == head) {
        tail = NULL;
        head = NULL;
    } else tail = temp->prev;
    delete temp;
    return true;
};
private:
    Node *head, *tail;
};
```

I run the following code against it:

```
char c1, c2;
cout << "start allocation" << endl;

LinkedList<int>* list = new LinkedList<int>();

for(ULONGLONG i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
    list->append(0);
}

cout << "allocation complete" << endl;

cin >> c1;

cout << "start deleting" << endl;

delete list;

cout << "done deleting" << endl;

cin >> c2;

cout << c2 << endl; // don't optimize read key away
```

So it allocates 100,000 int nodes and then it deletes them all. Allocating the space for all of the nodes is almost instantaneous while deleting them takes ~10 seconds. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: How are you timing this?

Comment: You might find that this is a good use for a pool allocator, since every node is the same size, and when a list is deleted, you can tell the allocator to delete the whole chunk of memory at once (no loop needed).

Comment: Unrelated, but `new` will never return `NULL` - you don't need to check it. If it can't allocate memory it will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: I never understood why so many C++ novices have their own linked list implementation ...

Comment: @honk Isn't it the first homework in every Data Structures class?

Comment: @BrendanLong - I am not doing any detailed timing. I can just tell at run-time that it's taking a long time. Watching Task Manager too for memory usage.

Comment: @honk - This is literally just me trying to get comfortable with C++, and LinkedList seems like the most trivial data structure implementation to cover many of the features of C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably an artifact of how the run time library deallocates memory. During allocation, finding a block for each node item is probably just a few operations to take the main pool, and split it into two parts and return the smaller part for your program's use. Freeing that block might include walking a free list to see if these small allocations can be combined into larger free blocks.

Comment: This seems like the most plausible answer, so I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try running in Release mode instead of Debug.

In Debug mode, when freeing a block, the runtime will do lots of sanity checks to make sure you didn't overwrite memory you didn't own, and it also scrubs the freed memory contents. In Release, all of that overhead goes away.

(Note that I'm assuming here that you are using Dev Studio. Other platforms have different rules for enabling memory checks, but your issue sounds very similar to my experiences with Dev Studio in Debug mode.)